# Wait for validation of multiple people in workflow designer

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

**Situation:**

I want to start a workflow when publishing a document from a doc library.
The workflow should do this:

-> Check the [type] and [domain] of the document.
-> Look in a separate list for a record that fits these 2 fields. Get the [responsables] field from this record.
-> Send a mail to EACH of these people.
-> Wait for ALL of these people to Validate the publish.
-> When everyone validated, all people from the 'Approval'-Sharepoint Group get an email, telling them that a document is waiting their approval.
-> as soon as 1 of them approves, the document is published.

Most of this is straightforward, but I'm stuck on the validation part: I can't figure out how to create my workflow so that it has to wait on the validation of all members in the column [responsables].

(both 2010 and 2013 workflows can be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SharePoint 2013 Workflow you can use the **Start a Task Process** action. In the properties under **Task Options** you can choose what constitutes task completion:

- Wait for all responses
- Wait for first response
- Wait for specific response
- Wait for percentage of a response

The **Wait for all responses** seems like the right answer, but this actually works by requiring everyone to respond (good) and returning the outcome the *majority* of the respondents chose (not so good).

If you want unanimous agreement from every respondent, then you should choose **Wait for percentage of a response** and set it to **100%**. Then, if not everyone agreed on that outcome, the default outcome will be returned instead. So the **Required Outcome** is the one you want everyone to agree on and the **default outcome** is what will be chosen if they don't.

[image: Task Options]

Comment: if we select Wait for percentage of a response in task outcome then the outcome Variable always returns "0" zero. So even we reject or approve or do anything else it will return zero why is that??